# Back button doesn't work after pushViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

This is how I am pushing a `UIViewController` :

```
[tabController setSelectedIndex:0];
UINavigationController *navController = [tabController selectedViewController];
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
NotificationViewController *notificationController = (NotificationViewController*)[mainStoryboard
 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"NotificationViewController"];
[navController pushViewController:notificationController animated:YES];
navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

When **NotificationViewController** is visible and I tap Back button, nothing happens. The previous `UIViewController` had a gesture in `UINavigationBar` but I have removed it in the `UIViewController`'s `viewWillDisappear`. But still the **NotificationViewController**'s Back button doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you think it should go when you are using a tabcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You probably call the `pushViewController` before the view is visible.

Make sure you don't call your `pushViewController` in the `viewDidLoad`.

Your `pushViewController` should be used only after `viewDidAppear` is called if you want your navigation controller to work properly with the back button. Otherwise, the navigation controller will add the title to the previous view controller without the redirection link.